# TP-Link Archer C9 shows empty data in advanced dashboard

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, firmware

I'm not sure if it is the right place to ask it, but I could not find much more information on the web about this issue. So, recently I bought a new wi-fi router for my home and I am pretty happy with it, but one thing is bothering me. The basic and the advanced dashboards panels are not showing any information.

On these dashboard, specially on the advanced one, I should see some important information like the internet connection, cpu/ram consume, wireless networks state, clients connected, etc. But all I got is a skeleton of the page.

Here's a screenshot:
[image: archer c9 v4 empty dashboard]

I have updated the firmware to the latest available but it did not help.

Can anyone give me a direction on what I could do to resolve this?

Comment: You may want to try compatibility mode in the browser. Try with IE if all else fails. I have trouble with some web-guis from Firefox, but not chrome. Sometimes it's vice versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it is not an answer, I found that it only happens when my printer is connected connected to the router and turned on. If it is not connected or on, the router is able to show all the information. Pretty sure that is a bug that could be fixed with a firmware upgrade, but there is no one available that does it.
Hope this helps.